# How to configure Rundeck Webhook to accept a file

Tags: rundeck

To give context on what I'm trying to achieve. I've created a Webhook that will run a job that accepts a file. The Webhook will be triggered by an external app that needs to pass a file. I can easily configure the Webhook to accept a raw JSON but I can't make it work to accept a file. Is this possible to do and if yes how can I configure the Webhook to accept a file.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Rundeck webhooks only expects JSON data, the best approach is to call the job via [API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html) or [RD-CLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/) to pass the file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60328253/10426011) the RD-CLI way and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64445793/10426011) the API way.